# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to call my Spring MVC controller from a JSP (I-Frame) and getting the following error on the browser

```
400 Bad Request,The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()
```

here is my JQuery code to send request to the server

```
jQuery("#login").live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
           jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:9002/myApp/springSecurity/login.json",
            xhrFields: {
                   withCredentials: true
                },
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain:true,
            data: jQuery("#loginForm").serialize(),
           contentType: "json",

            success: function(data, status) {
                alert(data);
                alert(status);
                if (data.loggedIn) {
                   // location.href = getHost() + '${ctx}/users';
                    //login_pannel

                } else {
                    loginFailed(data);
                }
            },
            error: loginFailed
        });

    });
```

This is my controller code

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("springSecurity/login.json")
public class SpringSecurityLoginController
{
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public SpringSecurityLoginStatus login(@RequestParam("j_username") final String username,
@RequestParam("j_password") final String password, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
    {

    LOG.info("Starting login process");
    return springSecurityLoginService.login(username, password, request, response);
    }
}
```

While hitting the submit button i am getting no error on the server but while looking at browser console output it showing me the following error

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - https://localhost:9002/myApp/springSecurity/login.json"
```

This is Error information from Mozilla Response header

```
the request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().
```

I am not sure what causing this behavior.
Additionally i am using Spring security to handle authentication and authorization.

**Edit**

I debugged more and find out that the form values are not being submitted to my controller when i checked the value of `j_username` and `j_password` in my Controller tey are coming as null.

i even tried `request.getParameter("param name");` but still same values are coming as null

Comment: could you provide the full request as shown by Firebug (request + data)?

Comment: remember you can upvote the answer as well. ;-)

Comment: @Stealth: Agree and its done.Thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your jQuery, try changing "contentType" to "dataType" ([more information here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).